# gradlew wrapper seems to be 'ignoring' my trusted certs

Tags: java, ssl, gradle, gradlew

When attempting to connect to a specified SSL server with a self signed certificate I understand I need to tell Java that this is a trusted host.

I have imported the certificate into the keystore and ran the following:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=my.jks SSLPoke my-host 443
```

Which prints

```
Successfully connected
```

Where SSLPoke is: https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029

So the connection can be made!

However, when on the same exact host with the same exact JKS file with the only difference being I'm using `./gradlew` to execute my task I get an Exception.

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 58 more
```

I've tried executing my gradlew tasklike:

```
./gradlew -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=my.jks myTask

GRADLE_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=my.jks ./gradlew myTask

export GRADLE_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=my.jks
./gradlew myTask
```

All of which produce the same Exception above. What is the '`correct`' way to use this property so `myTask` can complete?